# How to add a property to an array of elements which are not present in another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:-

```
var arr1 = [{
    "name": "A"
}, {
    "name": "B"
}, {
    "name": "C"
}, {
    "name": "D"
}];
```

I want to add a new property to each element which are not present in the second array.

```
var arr2 = [C,D]
```

The resulted array should be:-

```
arr1 = [{
    "name": "A",
    "country":"USA"
}, {
    "name": "B",
    "country":"USA"
}, {
    "name": "C"
}, {
    "name": "D"
}];
```

Can any one tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: My requirements were different. I have changed the previous question. Please help with the solution.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to add a new property to each element which are not present in the second array.

That **completely** changes the question you originally asked.

If the items are mutable, you'd just loop through the array adding the property to selected items. There are [many ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), such as `forEach`:

```
arr1.forEach(function(item) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
        item.country = "USA";
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "name": "A"
}, {
    "name": "B"
}, {
    "name": "C"
}, {
    "name": "D"
}];

var arr2 = ["C", "D"];

arr1.forEach(function(item) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
        item.country = "USA";
    }
});
console.log(arr1);
```

If they're immutable, you'd use `map` instead:

```
arr1 = arr1.map(function(item) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
        return /*...create item with `country = "USA"` here...*/;
    } else {
        return item;
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "name": "A"
}, {
    "name": "B"
}, {
    "name": "C"
}, {
    "name": "D"
}];

var arr2 = ["C", "D"];

arr1 = arr1.map(function(item) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
        return {name: item.name, country: "USA"};
    } else {
        return item;
    }
});
console.log(arr1);
```

---

**Original answer**: *(to [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46252242/1))*

You would loop over the resulting array adding the property. There are [many ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), such as `forEach`:

```
arr1.forEach(function(item) {
    item.country = "USA";
});
```

Technically, you *could* make it a side-effect of your `filter`, like this:

```
var arr1 = arr1.filter(function(item){
  if (arr2.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
    item.country = "USA";
    return true;
  };
  return false;
});
```

**BUT**, side-effects in `filter` callbacks (and similar) are generally not a great idea. Unless you know that the resulting array (`arr1`) is hundreds of thousands of entries, the second pass keeps things simple by filtering and then modifying.

Comment: The result as shown should have objects with name C and D, just not add the country. With filter those items would be dropped right? `map` sounds like a better option here?

Comment: @sabithpocker: The OP completely changed the question, so I'm re-answering it. But no, `map` wouldn't be the solution here (unless the items are immutable).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and add the property if the element is not present - by using the same comparison you were already using.

Comment: FYI, the OP completely changed the question. :-|